# Get input field value of current table row and append it to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a `<input>` field as well as a `<button>` in each table row. The table is created dynamically with data from a JSON file, however I don't think this is important.

The problem is that I want to be able to click on the button and append specific `<td>`s to another HTML element.

Basically, it's supposed to get the content of the first `<td>` in the table and append it together with the **value** of my input field. Using the above code works, however, only the first `<td>` of the table is always being appended correctly, while the input field value will stay the same for everything else.

I don't know how else to word it so here's a snippet:

```js
$("#medi-table").delegate(".btn-add-med", "click", function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            myCol = $this.closest("td"),
            myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
            targetArea = $("#contentHere"),
            $note = $(".note");
        targetArea.append(myRow.children().not(myCol).text() + '<br />' + $note.val() + '<br />');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="medi-table">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Medikament</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Add</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Medikamentenliste">
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="note"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button>
        </td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="note"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="note"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div><!--end medi-table-->

<div id="contentHere"></div>
```

The problem is that it only takes input from the very first input box in the first row, where I want them all to be individual.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the input value from the first item with the class `note`. You'll have to select this element from the current row, which you've stored in `myRow`

To do so, you can use jQuery's `find` method:

```
var currentNote = myRow.find(".note");
```

Check out the updated code:

```js
    $("#medi-table").delegate(".btn-add-med", "click", function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            myCol = $this.closest("td"),
            myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
            targetArea = $("#contentHere"),
            $note = myRow.find(".note");
        targetArea.append(myRow.children().not(myCol).text() + '<br />' + $note.val() + '<br />');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="medi-table">
      <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Medikament</th>
         <th>Notes</th>
         <th>Add</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="Medikamentenliste">
<tr><td>Item 1</td><td><input type="text" class="note"></input></td><td><button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 2</td><td><input type="text" class="note"></input></td><td><button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 3</td><td><input type="text" class="note"></input></td><td><button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button></td></tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </div><!--end medi-table-->

<div id="contentHere">
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Been sitting on this for hours, both of you helped me very much and fixed another problem I had as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to amend your logic to use DOM traversal to find the `input` related to the clicked button in the same way you're using it to get the text of the `td`. Try this:

```js
var $targetArea = $("#contentHere");

$("#medi-table").on('click', ".btn-add-med", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $row = $this.closest('tr'),
        value = $row.find('input').val(),
        text = $row.find('td:first').text();
    $targetArea.append(text + '<br />' + value + '<br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="medi-table">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Medikament</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Add</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Medikamentenliste">
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="note" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="note" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="note" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-add-med">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!--end medi-table-->

<div id="contentHere">

</div>
```

Also note that `input` elements do not have a closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me fix my other problem as well.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.